# trouble with styling in react application

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to apply some basic styling within a react component. I have a div and I want that div to take up 60% of the body. The body is set to 100vh. Simple enough, right? But for some reason, the div is taking up a significantly smaller portion than 60%. I tried the same exact styling with plain html and css and it worked perfectly. But for some reason I do it with React and the styling is off. Below I've included screenshots of the same thing with react vs html/css. The second screenshot is what I am trying to acheive. Here is the code ...

```
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="glass">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
      <p>This is an app</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;





* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to right top,  #65dfc9, #65dbeb);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1,p {
  text-align: center;
}

.glass {
  background: white;
  min-height: 80vh;
  width: 60%;
}
```

[image: this is what I'm getting in react]

[image: and this is what I get with plain html/css]

Comment: Try to examine it in the browser dev tools. That should give you some clues. React app has a "root" element, so your `<div>` is not a direct child of the `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using react, try applying the styles that you are using in `body` to `#root`, so your CSS should look like this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#root {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, #65dfc9, #65dbeb);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1,
p {
  text-align: center;
}

.glass {
  background: white;
  min-height: 80vh;
  width: 60%;
}
```

---

This is because a `<div id="root"></div>` is added by React by default as you can see on this elements tree:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D3YM.png)